# Scale(or normalize) an array like this in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

In numpy, the original array has the shape(2,2,2) like this

```
[[[0.2,0.3],[0.1,0.5]],[[0.1,0.3],[0.1,0.4]]]
```

I'd like to scale the array so that the max value of the a dimension is 1 like this:

As max([0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1]) is 0.2, and 1/0.2 is 5, so for the first element of the int tuple, multiple it by 5.

As max([0.3,0.5,0.3,0.4]) is 0.5, and 1/0.5 is 2, so for the second element of the int tuple, multiple it by 2

So the final array is like this:

```
[[[1,0.6],[0.5,1]],[[0.5,0.6],[0.5,0.8]]]
```

I know how to multiple an array with an integer in numpy, but I'm not sure how to multiple the array with different factor. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 4):

If your array = `a`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[[0.2,0.3],[0.1,0.5]],[[0.1,0.3],[0.1,0.4]]])
```

You can do this:

```
>>> a/np.amax(a.reshape(4,2),axis=0)
array([[[ 1. ,  0.6],
        [ 0.5,  1. ]],

       [[ 0.5,  0.6],
        [ 0.5,  0.8]]])
```